# Looping through file lines in bash

Tags: bash, shell

How can I loop through each line of a file and use that line in this command in bash ${/'#include "'/"a"} ? (I'm trying to replace the includes with something else in that line)

Comment: Show an example, this makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Use sed or awk to replace what you want. The example bellow all #include string found in fileA will be replaced for CustomTEXT. No need of loop in this case.

```
 sed -i  's/\#include/CustomTEXT/g' fileA
```